# 'local:Class1' is used like a markup extension but .. Is it glitch

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentPage with two ContentViews on it and i want to set the binding context for each of them.

```
<Label 
    BindingContext="{Binding Source ={local:ViewModel1 }}" 
    Text="{Binding LabelText}" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
<Label 
    BindingContext="{Binding Source ={local:ViewModel2 }}" 
    Text="{Binding LabelText}" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

And it is works but i have error -

```
 'local:ViewModel1' is used like a markup extension but
 'local:ViewModel2' is used like a markup extension but
```

For no reason

Comment: You probably need to make it `{x:Static local:ViewModel1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the code below.

ViewModel1.cs:

```
class ViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _labelText;
    public string LabelText
    {
        set
        {
            if (_labelText != value)
            {
                _labelText = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
               {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LabelText"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _labelText;
        }
    }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        this.LabelText = "hello_1";
    }
}
```

ViewModel2.cs:

```
class ViewModel2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _labelText2;
    public string LabelText
    {
        set
        {
            if (_labelText2 != value)
            {
                _labelText2 = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LabelText"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _labelText2;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ViewModel2()
    {
        this.LabelText = "hello_2";
    }
 }
```

Xaml:

```
<ContentView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            FontSize="Large"
            Text="{Binding LabelText}">
            <Label.BindingContext>
                <local:ViewModel1 />
            </Label.BindingContext>
        </Label>
        <Label
            FontSize="Large"
            Text="{Binding LabelText}">
            <Label.BindingContext>
                <local:ViewModel2 />
            </Label.BindingContext>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

[image]

For more details about how to set the BindingContext of the Label, you could refer to the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: BindingContext in XML attribute syntax

To suppress the warning and if using **XML attribute syntax** is not a requirement, convert the `BindingContext="{Binding Source ={local:ViewModel1}}"` to its corresponding **property element syntax** as follows.

```
<Label
    Text="{Binding LabelText}" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Label.BindingContext>local:ViewModel1</Label.BindingContext>
</Label>
```

**Remark:**

As `BindingContext` is of type `object`, you don't need `Binding` markup extension.
Your `BindingContext="{Binding Source ={local:ViewModel1}}"` can be simplified as `BindingContext="{local:ViewModel1}"`. However, both trigger the same warnings (not errors) as you said in your question.

## Option 2: Using ResourceDictionary

Add the following to the ancestor of your `Label`. Any ancestor is fine depending the scope you want to achieve.

```xml
<AnyAncestorYouChoose.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel1 x:Key="vm1"/>
</AnyAncestorYouChoose.Resources>
```

If you don't know which ancestor to choose, `ContentPage` is ok, so the markup becomes

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel1 x:Key="vm1"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Now you can use the static resource as follows.

```
<Label BindingContext="{StaticResource Key=vm1}"
    Text="{Binding LabelText}" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
</Label>
```

`BindingContext="{StaticResource Key=vm1}"` can also be simplified as `BindingContext="{StaticResource vm1}"` because `Key` is marked as the [content property](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/2df96b1960ee2c4c52e6f5a2f00c95dc779b8889/src/Controls/src/Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticResourceExtension.cs#L7) of `StaticResourceExtension`.