# Is it safe to ignore "Type local:MyViewModel is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension"?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

The objective is to instantiate `local:MyViewModel` without constructor injection as well as without static resource.

The **property element syntax** version below works fine.

```xml
<Label.BindingContext>local:MyViewModel</Label.BindingContext>
```

My attempt with **XML attribute syntax** below also works.

```xml
<Label ... BindingContext="{local:MyViewModel}"/>
```

However Visual Studio Community warns me with

> Type `local:MyViewModel` is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension.

#### Question:

- Is it safe to ignore this warning?
- Is there any trick to suppress the  warning?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999751/localclass1-is-used-like-a-markup-extension-but-is-it-glitch), it could be helpful to you.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT: The link does not help because the accepted answer does not use **XML attribute syntax** as what I want in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the markup extension implementation for WPF. Check if it will work in Xamarin too.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace CommonCore
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Type))]
    public class CreateInstanceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        [ConstructorArgument("instanceType")]
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public Type InstanceType { get; set; }

        [ConstructorArgument("instanceValue")]
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public string InstanceValue { get; set; }

        public CreateInstanceExtension(Type instanceType, string instanceValue)
            : this(instanceValue)
        {
            InstanceType = instanceType;
        }
        public CreateInstanceExtension(string instanceValue)
            : this()
        {
            InstanceValue = instanceValue;
        }

        public CreateInstanceExtension()
        { }

        private static TypeExtension typeExtension;

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            Type type = InstanceType;
            string value = InstanceValue;
            if (type is null)
            {
                value = value?.Trim(" \t\r\n".ToCharArray());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    string typeName = null;
                    if (value[0] == '(')
                    {
                        int end = value.IndexOf(')');
                        if (end > 0)
                        {
                            typeName = value.Substring(1, end - 1);
                            value = value.Substring(end + 1).Trim(" \t\r\n".ToCharArray());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        typeName = value;
                        value = null;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeName))
                    {
                        (typeExtension ??= new TypeExtension()).TypeName = typeName;
                        type = (Type)typeExtension.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (type is null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("The type must be specified.");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            else
            {
                if (TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type) is not TypeConverter converter)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException("There is no TypeConverter for the specified type.");
                }
                var target = ((IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)))?.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
                if (target?.Language.GetEquivalentCulture() is CultureInfo culture)
                    return converter.ConvertFromString(null, culture, value);
                return converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in WPF:

```xml
<Label ... DataContext="{commcore:CreateInstance (local:MyViewModel)}"/>
<Label ... DataContext="{commcore:CreateInstance local:MyViewModel}"/>
<Label ... DataContext="{commcore:CreateInstance (sys:Double)123.456}"/>
```